# Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/Users/user-name/.config/postcssrc'

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm, postcss

I'm trying to run a project locally using npm run serve but I keep getting an error regarding postcss which I can't find any solution for.

I'm simply copying the project files from another project and pasting them into this one. The original project doesn't give me any of these issues.

The error is described as follows:

```
ERROR in ./src/App.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&id=7ba5bd90&lang=scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??clonedRuleSet-22.use[1]!./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/stylePostLoader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??clonedRuleSet-22.use[2]!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??clonedRuleSet-22.use[3]!./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/index.js??ruleSet[0].use[0]!./src/App.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&id=7ba5bd90&lang=scss)
    Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
    Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/Users/user-name/.config/postcssrc'
     @ ./node_modules/vue-style-loader/index.js??clonedRuleSet-22.use[0]!./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??clonedRuleSet-22.use[1]!./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/stylePostLoader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??clonedRuleSet-22.use[2]!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??clonedRuleSet-22.use[3]!./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/index.js??ruleSet[0].use[0]!./src/App.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&id=7ba5bd90&lang=scss 4:14-389 15:3-20:5 16:22-397
     @ ./src/App.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&id=7ba5bd90&lang=scss 1:0-447 1:0-447
     @ ./src/App.vue 5:0-63
     @ ./src/main.js 7:0-28 18:20-23
```

I'm currently using vue 3 and node -v 14.

Comment: I'm also seeing this problem. Seems like postcss introduced a breaking change by bumping a patch version number... it happened in version `8.4.19`, `8.4.20`, `8.4.21` (not 100% sure about this information though). I reverted my last `yarn upgrade` commit to some older dependency status and it was fine. In my case, this happened because I run the command as user A inside a subfolder of user B.

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar error in a project and could fix either by disable the automatic configuration of the postcss loader  in the webpack config file (in my case the `vue.config.js`):

```
module.exports = {
...
   css: {
...
      loaderOptions: { postcss: { postcssOptions: { config: false } } }
   }
```

or by creating a simple postcss configuraton file in the project root directory `postcss.config.js`  :

```
module.exports = {};
```

Comment: On point. Solved my problem by creating a postcss.config.js file in my root directory

Answer (score 0):

### 1. Update npm

Run `sudo npm install -g npm@latest`

### 2. Clear a bug from earlier npm versions

Run `sudo chown -R 501:20 "/Users/{your_username}/.npm"`